# contenttype field in serializer without model

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Here is the class that only takes object_id and content_type as post request and for that I want to create contenttype field  in serializerclass which must show all contenttype object of project while passing data from  browsable api.
Can somebody know how to do that

And my code look like:

in views.py

```
from rest_framework.views import APIView
class Snippetviews(APIView):
    serializer_class=SnippetSerializer
    def post(self,request):
        data = request.data
        object_id = data.get("object_id",None)
        content_type = data.get("content_type")
        ctype = ContentType.objects.get(model=content_type)
        obj_model = ctype.get_object_for_this_type(id=object_id)
```

in serializers.py

```
class SnippetSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    object_id=serializers.IntegerField()
   #for this field i don't know what to do..
    content_type =
```

For this particular view,there is no model.I only want from this is to get object_id and content_type . with this value,i want to change status  of model  Product and Forum . There are two model in project which looks

```
class Product:
      name=models.CharField(max_length=10)
      status=models.BooleanField(default=True)

class Forum:
      name=models.CharField(max_length=10)
      status=models.BooleanField(default=True)
```

Comment: can you provide us your models?

Comment: post edited have a look

Comment: ContentType should also be a model - `ctype = ContentType.objects.get(model=content_type)` from your code